# Is there a way to interpret higher power loss functions?

Tags: loss-functions

As I understand, finding the mode is equivalent to minimising the 0-1 expected loss. Likewise the median is equivalent to minimising the expected loss of an absolute value loss function and the mean to a square loss function. So what about fourth power loss functions and other higher powers which are even? Are they ever useful or interpretable?

As an aside: are there other nice correspondences I should be aware of? I'm vaguely aware that minimising the cross-entropy is probably minimising the KL divergence...